# How can reconnect when Strophe Status is disconnected

Tags: jquery, javascript, strophe

I want make Strophe reconnect auto when it's Status 
disconnected, I write code look like follow:

```
if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) { 
    connection.connect(setting.userId, setting.password, 
onReConnect, 3600); 
}
```

but it's not work. How can I resolve it? 
Thanks everyone.

Regards

Comment: Can you post your complete function which is called on connection established.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using openfire. Not sure about other servers, but in openfire there is a server variable called xmpp.httpbind.client.idle. It is to set the period of time the client could remain ideal. The default value is 30. If ideal time passes the the given value, server will automatically terminate the connection. Either you increase this value, or you send a kinda heartbeat every once in a while. it could be a simple presence stanza.
There is one more thing I think you need to consider. You shouldn't store password in any javascript variables, for safety reasons, it is better to try to attach to the existing session if you missed the connection. Strophe code is quite simple just use, connection.attach.

Comment: OP asked how to reconnect *client* when disconnected, we don't even know if he's using Openfire. Nor this answer is about how will it *reconnect* when Strophe disconnects from it.

Comment: But this is at least useful to prevent the disconnection in some cases.